# How to have a source code and IDE on local laptop and run it on another machine inside the docker container?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, docksal

I'm using an "old" MacBook Pro 2015 with "just" 16GB of RAM for developing some complex websites based on Drupal. As a tool stack, I'm using [Docksal](https://docs.docksal.io/) (a Docker-based env) and PHPStorm as an IDE.
Because the Drupal site is complex it eats up almost all my memory and the NFS sharing is also very slow. I have another machine (an old Mac Mini) with 16GB of RAM. My idea is to have the code and IDE on my laptop and run the heavy Docker on a second machine.

I found the [Docker Context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/) tool and I've configured it to connect to the Docker host on the second machine, so now I can run docker commands on my laptop and they will be executed on the second machine.

But I'm still missing the last part of the puzzle - how can I configure Docker and Docksal to sync my code from the laptop to the Docker image on another machine? Is it possible at all?

Also, I found a [Mutagen.io](https://mutagen.io/) but it is not supported in Docksal and it's not clear how to combine everything together.

Comment: Have you considered fixing these memory problems properly? "Just 16 GB of RAM" is way above anything else I've seen in productive PHP projects

Comment: Sure, I will address memory issues in the future, but now I'm more interested in the opportunity to have a dedicated home server that will run all the heavy docker containers and I will free up my laptop for IDE and the Browser.

Comment: Why not use a proper server and copy the code there on each modification? That's what PhpStorm supports out of the box, and with memory problems, you should remove as much complexitiy from the system as possible (which means: Docker)

Comment: @Andrii did you managed this issue in some way? I just point out that Mutagen can be used inside Docksal without any problem, moreover I created a custom global command for Docksal to easily manage Docksal and Mutagen together. 
[Here](https://github.com/docksal/docksal/issues/249) you can find some reading about Docksal, Mutagen and file system performance under different scenarios, while [here](https://github.com/nicoschi/mutagen-for-docksal/)  is my repo with command line tool I'm using with some heavy Drupal projects.